# sed string path change

Tags: linux, shell-script, sed

I need change in a terminal all occurrences of the string path `"/../path/file.extension"` to `"/path/file.extension"` of my file using a sed command.

Notice that i just need replace "/../" to "/".

I have been tried something like this, but not work: `sed -i \"s/..\//\//g\" myfile.php`

edit

This config is for use in a `package.json` and I have some limitations beacuse this.

[image]

Comment: This question has been cross-posted at AskUbuntu at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1114297/help-with-a-sed-command

Comment: I'll vote to reopen if you make it clearer what the error is (in the json).

Comment: Please [don't post pictures of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just replacing beginning `/..` with blank.

```
echo "/../path/file.extension" | sed 's|/..||'
```

Comment: That would remove the three first characters of _any_ absolute path.

Comment: works, but `sed 's|/..||' ../../myfile.php` is not saving the file. and the command `sed -i 's|/..||' ../../myfile.php` returns me `sed: 1: "../../myfile.php": invalid command code .`

Comment: You solution removes all comments in my code // my comment

Comment: Your solution helps me to find a correct answer. I change my config in the `package.json` file to `"changeIndexFile": "sed -i -e \"s|'/..|'|\" ../../indecente-api/index.php",` and now it's working great. Basically the command pick all the occurrences starts with `'/` and remove it with two more right chars and adds `'` the "hack" to `'` was necessary because your solution remove the comments code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
echo '/../path/file.extension' | sed -e 's@/\.\.@@g'
```

It will give output `/path/file.extension`. It replaces `/..` with blank.

Or if you are using some file then you can use:

```
sed -i 's@/\.\./path/file\.extension@/path/file.extension@g' myfile.php
```

Comment: No works. the file `package.json` dosen't accept the escape \.

Comment: @FabianoLothor I didn't get what you want to say?

Comment: I'm go update my question.

Comment: I update the question.

Comment: I solve the problem, thanks for you help!